# Yet another "draw a box" Question

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

The following problem is a [common interview question](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/89uhql/wtf_why_did_i_fail_this_interview_question/), thus dull answers are discouraged. Go short or creative, best if both:

*Create the following pattern*

```
###########
##       ##
# #     # #
#  #   #  #
#   # #   #
#    #    #
#   # #   #
#  #   #  #
# #     # #
##       ##
###########
```

In case you cry ["dupe"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93707/draw-an-ascii-rectangle), 
 I see your point but this is a slight variation and I hope it differs enough to be greenlit.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125383/66833), [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/141094/66833)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen an identical question but I can't find it now.

Comment: As this is just the output for the question linked by Angs when the input is 11, it is essentially a duplicate

Comment: @Angs why did you revoke your comment?!

Comment: @mbx When the question is closed as a duplicate the proposal comment is automatically removed.

Comment: @user56656 maybe not the best design decision in the first place - that comment was referenced by 2 other comments already

Comment: Hello, how can i add my solution?

Comment: @AliISSA The question was closed so no additional answers are allowed. You can answer [this open question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91068/creating-a-crossed-square) if you want.

Comment: I think I've mentioned it before, it surprises me how often the people who vote for a question to be closed as a duplicate have already answered the question, maybe gained rep for their answer then deny anyone else the chance to compete with them. No personal attack on anyone intended. I have the utmost respect for everyone here.  As I said it just surprises me that this is seen as "community friendly".

Comment: @ElPedro I'd say that's at least partly due to the fact that people who have just answered the question are both aware of the question and active on the site at the moment, and are thus more likely than other users to notice when a dupe target is proposed.

Comment: @ElPedro In addition, this question was VTC'ed by me and Angs well after Erik posted his Charcoal solution, and he hammered the question closed because he believes it is a duplicate. There would also be no need for him to delete his answer. If he's posted an answer, then immediately hammered it closed, then it's more of an issue.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｐ¬↙×⁶#‖Ｏ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9jaGFyY29hbP//77ywwqzihpnDl@KBtiPigJbvvK/CrP//)

Comment: Never seen Charchoal before - Short Question: The linked possible dupe by Angs contains an [8 byte Charcoal solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126601/1187) which apparently does not work anymore. Any Ideas why?

Comment: @mbx The deverbosifier is buggy.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer :| crap

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
６#×：＼ω↷１１╋１１╋┼
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE2JTIzJUQ3JXVGRjFBJXVGRjNDJXUwM0M5JXUyMUI3JXVGRjExJXVGRjExJXUyNTRCJXVGRjExJXVGRjExJXUyNTRCJXUyNTND,v=1)

uses an older version of Canvas as in the latest one I undid a thing I undid with a logical reason..

Comment: So you wrote your own language for that, nice!

Comment: @mbx creating golfing languages is fun :p Shorter solutions might appear though

Comment: @dzaima and one did :P

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 92 bytes

```r
write(c(" ","#")[1+!!`[<-`(`[<-`(diag(11)+diag(11)[11:1,],c(1,11),,1),,c(1,11),1)],1,11,,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYdBCoAgFAWvkr/NF1@Lt41uIoJhEW4l6Pi/JFzMMNPMnlbvU4vKJJBZfGRwLsdtyfr7qPulpA8jIrkSCUWJb4HOGPqEXoCIN3sB)

That is...a lot of `1`s.

Comment: Serves me right for coding a closed question. Used a sligthtly different indexing based approach for 86. Just pasting here for reference. ``[<-`(matrix(" ",a<-11,a),c(n<-1:a,110+n,n*10+1,n*12-a,a*n-10,a*n),"#")`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>129</s> 122 bytes

- Saved seven bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
*s;f(j,k){for(j=puts(s="###########")-2;--j;)printf("#%*c%*c%*c\n",k-(k==5),k-5?35:32,10-k-k,35,k=j>5?10-j:j,35);puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwEEXvkiLMlAxoQzYdYi/iRgKRzmAsTbsSzx4jXfh5i/9WL9Ijxlr7wgnEKr7TawUJy74VKMF0/xmkgYmEcVnnvCUw3amPB7dsrBJoCB7b8ZPzoxvs5UxKap23GuTqp@YySnPkI4D8qc/7nKF14Sdf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 100 bytes

```python
for i in range(11):s=[" "]*11 if 0<i<10 else ["#"]*11;s[0]=s[10]=s[0+i]=s[10-i]="#";print ''.join(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYoxDoMwEAS/snIKIAjkSxngJRYFhQ0XRWfkc8PrDYJmRzPa/chblE8pISYwWJAWWX1N1Hx1cgZmfhOBA@zII1n4v3o487r7oM7Okzq617b8SHfxegx7Ysmoqv4XWWptSjkB)

**Explanation** :

```python
for i in range(11):
  s=[" "]*11 if 0<i<10 else ["#"]*11;    #Ternary Expression to set cap lists 
  s[0]=s[10]=s[0+i]=s[10-i]="#";    #Set '#'s in the right spots
  print ''.join(s)    #Convert to string and print
```